# My Laravel 4 app shows errors when uploaded to my website

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel 4. When I upload my app to my website it shows errors. How should I configure it to fix it?

```
Warning: require(__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a4651312/public_html/laravel/public/index.php on line 21 

PHP Error Message  Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a4651312/public_html/laravel/public/index.php on line 21.
```

I put my app (name laravel) in `public_htmt` and sent a link from default.html to public.

Comment: The `public_htmt` should represent your `public` folder in local.

Comment: `chmod 777 app/storage`